# How to gzip the result while writing in Python?

Tags: python, gzip, fwrite

I am parsing some code and writing the result into 11 text files but the problem is that my ssd cannot afford the normal sizes . that is why I am looking for a way to write the results in a gzipped format.any idea?

my code:

```
from __future__ import print_function, division
import os
from glob import glob
from os import getpid
from time import time
from sys import stdout
import resource
from multiprocessing import Pool
import subprocess
try:
    import ujson as json
except ImportError:
    try:
        import simplejson as json
    except ImportError:
        import json


path = '/data/data/A.1/unzipped/*.A.1'
print("Running with PID: %d" % getpid())



def process_file(file):
    start = time()
    filename =file.split('/')[-1]
    print(file)
    with open('/data/data/A.1/%s_DI' %filename, 'w') as w:
        with open(file, 'r') as f:
            for n, line in enumerate(f):
                d = json.loads(line)
                try:

                    domain = d['rrname']
                    ips = d['rdata']
                    for i in ips:
                        print("%s|%s" % (i, domain), file=w)
                except:
                    pass


if __name__ == "__main__":
    files_list = glob(path)
    cores = 12
    print("Using %d cores" % cores)
    pp = Pool(processes=cores)
    pp.imap_unordered(process_file, files_list)
    pp.close()
    pp.join()
```

Comment: If you google `python gzip` or anything reasonably similar, the very first thing that comes up is the docs for the `gzip` library in the stdlib, which have a nice example that does exactly what you're asking for.

Answer (score 4):

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, filename='logfile')
# ....
with gzip.GzipFile('/data/data/A.1/{0}_DI.gz'.format(filename), 'wb') as w:
    logging.debug('{} Opened for writing'.format(filename))
    with open(file, 'r') as f:
        logging.debug('{} opened for reading'.format(file))
        for n, line in enumerate(f):
            d = json.loads(line)
            logging.debug('{0} <=== json loaded from {1}'.format(d, line))
            try:
                domain = d['rrname']
                logging.debug('domain: {}'.format(domain))
                ips = d['rdata']
                logging.debug('ips: {}'.format(ips))
                for i in ips:
                    print("%s|%s" % (i, domain), file=w)
            except:
                pass
```

Hope that helps...

Comment: thanks @hd1 . DO you know if writing in gzip format is slower than normal?

Comment: @user2058811 Cut out that piece of code and try to get it working on its own, in a separate script. If it still doesn't work, ask a new question.

Comment: @PeterWood it works without the writing part. Something is wrong with the writing: {}_DI.gz'.format(filename) does not create the files

Comment: @user2058811 it shouldn't be any slower. Are you getting any exceptions?

Comment: Try using the numbered plaeholders

Comment: @hd1 not . just it does not do anything

Comment: Add logging statements and turn up logging. Edit your question with the output of the logging statements.

Comment: You're swallowing exceptions. Modify your `except` statement to catch an exception `except Exception, e: print e`.

Comment: @PeterWood Good catch, I prefer `logging.fatal('Exception: str(e)', e)` in lieu of printing, but good catch all the same

Comment: @hd1 I was addressing @user2058811 really, as it's in their initial code. If printing to file `w` is raising an exception, that will be a good place to start debugging. Cheers.

Comment: Yes, I know, but stylistically, it's better to use the logger, as opposed to a raw print.

Comment: @hd1 Where the output of logging statement is saved? I defined a log file in the same directory and it is empty

Comment: It will appear on the console. If you want it in a file, please see my change to the code.